# Web API Corruption in Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I've encountered two oddities concerning a Web API stateless service in my service fabric cluster.  The first regarding missing properties on the response to a call to a stateful service.  The second being a critical error when a response to GET was changed from a class to a struct.  Details below.

#### Issue #1 - Missing Properties

I have a three projects:

- A class library with a class called Person.  The two projects below utilize this library view a private nuget package.
- A Stateless Web API, which has a GET to retrieve all Persons.
- A Stateful Service, implementing a ReliableDictionary which holds all persons.  The Stateless Web API calls a method which returns all person from this dictionary.

The issue is that I've recently updated my class library to give Person some new properties (say, CreatedOn).  Both the Stateless Web API and Stateful Service have the latest version of this package and were deployed (overridding, not upgrading).  The Stateful Service correctly recognizes and stores these new properties.  However, the Web API is somehow not creating an object without those new properties.  It's not like they are null, they just simply do not exist!

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling nuget package, as well as, clearing out bin/obj folders.  Neither works. However, creating a new Web API Service fabric project, does work.

Any ideas, or has my project somehow been corrupted?

Pictures of properties:

#### Issue #2 - Struct Crashing Web API

This may be related to the first issue, and uses the same libraries and services.  I tried changing the Person object to a struct, but any call to the api then throws the following error:

*{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.get_SubRoutes()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"
}*

Again, trying this in another, identical Web API project works just fine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same when I used badly formatted route
example

[Route("/api/info")]

correct is

[Route("api/info")]

Comment: Looks like this was the case.  Thanks!